# Compiler error message line / column number reporting with Unicode

Tags: unicode, compiler-errors

Is there a standard/common way to give compiler-style error messages that point to a line and column when the input is in a Unicode format?

For example, a very common compiler error messages format is:
"filename:line_number:column_number: error message", e.g.:

- (From GCC): `bad.c:1:10: syntax error, unexpected STRING`
- (From a custom tool) `input.dat:45:3: expected String_Literal, found ';'`,

This is unambiguous when the input is a fixed 8-bit encoding, such as ISO-8859-1. But when the input is Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc), what does (or should) "column" mean in this case? Which byte? Which code-point? Which grapheme? Is there any tool that sets a precedent choosing one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *column* should refer to non-combining Unicode code points. Both parts of a *surrogate pair* (in UTF-16) should share a column. A *combining diacritical mark* should share a column with the base character it modifies. This may apply to other non-spacing code points as well.

Comment: I think I found what I want that matches up with your answer as well. Extended grapheme clusters, as defined in http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/ . I'm able to get at this through ICU's BreakIterator.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU coding standards say that the Unicode character width should be used to calculate the column number: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Errors.

This should be compatible to how Emacs, which consumes error messages, calculates column numbers: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Columns.html.

There seems to be a bug about it in GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49973.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal answer to the question how the "column" value is interpreted in error messages of compilers and similar tools.  Apart from the fact that it is one-based, which almost all tools and editors seem to honour, no standard has been established towards one of the different solutions that you mention, as far as I know.  As far as I can see using my Ubuntu 14.04 system, even vanilla GCC and vanilla Emacs will disagree in the handling of tab characters:  GCC seems to count a tab as one character, while Emacs interprets a tab as however many characters are actually indented for it.

What follows is my personal suggestion.  I would love to get feedback on it.  For anyone who is writing a tool that outputs such error messages, I will suggest to count the bytes, and not do any special handling of tabs, Unicode, surrogate pairs or combining characters.  This is most useful because users almost never read the column number.  Instead, the column number is almost always parsed by a user interface.  This should make it easier for both the tool outputting the message as well as for the application displaying the message.  End of my proposal.

Pragmatically, I would output whatever is more convenient in the programming language that you are using.